# How do I play audio through a Bluetooth headset in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, audio, bluetooth, headset

I recently did an in-place upgrade from Vista to Windows 7 RTM.  For the most part, things have gone brilliantly. The only issue I've been facing is regarding my Bluetooth headset, a Dell BH200.  The laptop is an Inspiron 1720.

I can get Windows 7 to pair with the headset, and even get the Bluetooth settings to show that there is stereo audio available.  The problem is that the Bluetooth headset never shows up in my sound output devices list.  I've uninstalled and reinstalled the Bluetooth drivers from Dell, tried turning on/off all of the features of the headset, removing the Bluetooth driver and letting Windows re-detect and install, but nothing has worked so far.

I guess I should mention that the headset worked fine in Vista.  How can I make it work?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

After a couple of hours of agony, searching online for proper drivers for my Motorola HT820 bluetooth headset, I had to do these in order to pair my headset successfully with my Win 7 RC system

1. Uninstall Broadcom bluetooth software
2. [Download and install this](http://63.66.78.2/support/drivers/getFile.asp?id=23452&dscr=Broadcom%20BRM2045%20and%20BRM2046%20Bluetooth%20Driver%20Version%206.2.1.500&uid=50178877)
3. Now, add your device, Windows 7 should automatically download various drivers
4. Go to your bluetooth devices, see an entry for your headset, right click, properties, services tab and make sure headset option is selected
5. After all these, right click volume icon, playback devices and you should find an entry for the connected bluetooth headset. Set that as default and you're good to go!
6. If there still isn't any sound, you may still need to Connect your Bluetooth headset to your PC/Laptop. Go to Devices and Printers/Bluetooth Devices, right click the icon for your headset, click "Control" and on the pop-up window, click "Connect".

Comment: I finally got a chance to try this.  So far so good.  I'll wait for a reboot or two before I'm convinced it's an entire fix, only because I've read in forum posts about fixes that didn't last, but I should know by the end of the week.  Thanks!

Comment: That seems to have fixed it.  Funny to download a driver from Gateway to fix a Dell laptop. :)

Comment: Works without doing step 1 -- at least for me. Thanks Vivek!

Comment: The link stopped working. Found a mirror at: http://www.mediafire.com/?ws7m17o9p661p2f

Comment: Bah: "No Bluetooth device was detected. ...[plug it in] in order to continue installation". Meanwhile, BT radio is on the mobo. Looks like it won't work.

Comment: What kind of black magic is this? I've got an Amilo pi 3560 and couldn't connect my LG tone HBS-700's. I tried the fujitsu website, I tried microsoft, broadcom scanning and updating tools. Nothing worked. Then I just installed this driver set and it worked flawlessly... o.O

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me.  I ran into the same issue that @jcollum posted, but I fixed it by going into the download's "Win64" folder and running the installer directly there ("Inst.exe"), rather than running the root folder's "Setup.exe".

Comment: Link appears to now be broken

Comment: Can we get an updated link for this?

Comment: I'm on Step 6 with Windows 7 and a generic BH-M20C headset, but there is no "control" or "connect" option when I right-click this (or any other) icon...only Create Shortcut, Troubleshoot, Remove Device, and Properties... and I already tried all 4 of those...

Comment: Found the file at http://63.66.78.2/support/drivers/getFile.asp?id=23452&dscr=Broadcom%20BRM2045%20and%20BRM2046%20Bluetooth%20Driver%20Version%206.2.1.500&uid=50178877 when searching for `Broadcom BRM2045 BRM2046 Bluetooth Driver Version 6.2.1.500`

Comment: @Gerhard Now that's gone.

Answer (score 7):

You'll need a driver that supports bluetooth A2DP on the Windows 7 machine.  There are drivers for bluetooth the transport layer and then there are drivers for the bluetooth audio profile support.  They are separate.

The first thing to do is to check Windows Update after you pair the devices.  Does that find a driver?  If not, you'll have to get the driver from Dell.

Update: I'm told that Dell uses Broadcom for their Bluetooth driver.  Try this site for drivers:  http://www.broadcom.com/support/bluetooth/update.php

Comment: That was a nice tip, and there was a driver that claims to work with Windows 7 (RC); however, it will not install. I fear I've fallen prey to the "Only from Dell" syndrome that I've experienced with video drivers on Dell based notebooks.

Comment: This worked for my Belkin f8t012xx1 bluetooth adapter. Now I can pair my Logitech Freepulse stereo headphones. Thanks!

Comment: The Broadcom link is probably the best "generic" link to updated drivers for a Broadcom device.

Answer (score 7):

I wanted to share this information with anyone in case it's helpful:

I contacted Dell support with the issue, and they said that I needed to download the Widcomm Bluetooth Stack software driver and gave me the following link:

> http://www.broadcom.com/support/license.php?file=SetupBtwDownloadSE.exe

I downloaded it, ran it, and it seemed to install fine, but then right at the end I got the error:

> This software is not for this system, contact DELL for support.

When I replied to Dell CS with the error message, they said, "I see that the issue requires advanced software troubleshooting. As a Hardware technician, I do not have sufficient expertise regarding the issue. I suggest you to contact our advanced software troubleshooting team, Dell On Call." Dell On Call is a fee-based service. I didn't (and won't be) calling.

UPDATE: **I finally got it to work!** Uninstall any Bluetooth software you might have installed, then install the driver from Dell (yes, the 2007 version), but here's the kicker, install it as an Administrator! For some reason, that updated the firmware and now my headphones are working!

Comment: Well, still no luck.  I've even tried the suggestion that I found on Dell's forums where some people reported installing the 370 driver worked for them, but it has still failed.

Comment: This solution worked for me using a Belkin plug-and-forget Bluetooth USB (F8T016) on a Toshiba notebook running Windows 7 Home Premium. It's streaming music excellently over [a Blue Music Streamer](http://www.mrhandsfree.com/en/shop/1181-music-accessories/product/2554-blue-music-streamer).

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem connecting a Samsung WEP350 Bluetooth headset to an HP laptop. If you install the following software it will work beautifully:

> http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/SoftwareDescription.jsp?lang=en&cc=us&swItem=ob-76382-1&jumpid=reg_R1002_USEN

Comment: Thanks! This worked for my HP laptop trying to connect to a set of Sharper Image Bluetooth KO 500 speakers.

Comment: Site does not exist anymore, ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED, and there is no description of what software it is, so I can't search their site.

Answer (score 1):

Did you use the software from Dell for Windows Vista to install it?

I'm checking [the manual](http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/acc/P130684/en/OM/om_en.pdf) right now to see if I can find anything.

Try the following:

> 1. Right-click on the Volume icon in the Windows taskbar.
> 2. Choose Playback Devices.
> 3. Right-click on Headset Earphone.
> 4. Choose Set as Default Device.
> 5. Click OK.

or

> Your Bluetooth adapter does not have
>   the required Bluetooth profiles (A2DP,
>   Handset and Hands-free) in order to
>   transmit sound. In Vista must install
>   a driver to get the necessary
>   Bluetooth profiles to listen to audio.
>   Otherwise, Bluetooth will not be
>   listed as a mixer device and Vista may
>   prompt you to install “additional
>   drivers” after you pair the BH200.

Comment: It does not show up in my playback devices.  I've tried both the Dell drivers as well as letting Windows install what it thinks it needed, neither track worked.

The headset did work under Vista just fine, it is Windows 7 that is not working.  According to the properties of the bluetooth headset (in devices) it has A2DP, Handset and Hands Free.  I've tried different combinations of enabled, disabling those various profiles.

Comment: comment from [Paul](http://superuser.com/users/39413/paul): I have motorola S805 stero headset which work fine with window xp and my phone but has problem with window 7. It see my headset as regular bluetooh. I follow Ivo Flipse, slove problem riht away

Answer (score 1):

How did you get it working in Vista ? I got a list for you if your hardware doesn't work. Check [What to Do if your hardware doesn't work in Windows 7](http://www.windows7hacker.com/index.php/2009/08/what-can-i-do-if-my-hardware-doesnt-work-in-windows-7/) taken from technet forum

> 1. Check Windows Update for any updated drivers for that device.
> 2. Check the Microsoft Windows 7 Hardware Support page.
> 3. If your computer came pre-installed with Windows XP or
>      Windows Vista, check the computer
>      manufacturers website for Vista
>      compatible drivers.
> 4. Did you try to install the drivers in Vista Compatibility Mode?
> 5. Did you right click and select the Run as Admin option?
> 6. If you purchased the device from a retail vendor, check the device
>      manufacturers website for either Vista
>      compatible or the latest Windows Beta
>      drivers. (ie: Dell has Windows 7 Beta
>      drivers for many of their newer NVIDIA
>      graphics cards)
> 7. Search this forum using the device name and model as search
>      keywords. Another user may have found
>      a workaround for the problem you are
>      experiencing.
> 8. Check to make sure that the hardware manufacturer will be
>      supporting that device with Windows 7
>      compatible drivers. We have learned in
>      past beta testing that some
>      manufacturers will not be supporting
>      the new operating system with updated
>      drivers for particular, outdated
>      device model.
> 9. If none of this works for you, you may simply need to wait until
>      Windows 7 drivers are available for
>      that device.

Hope those tips helps Cheers :)

Comment: In Vista, the headset showed up in my playback devices.  Occasionally I would have to reset the default, but it wasn't bad.  Here's how I fixed that issue in Vista: http://blog.palehorse.net/2007/10/12/what-to-do-when-your-bluetooth-headset-stops-working-in-vista/  Of course since the headset doesn't appear in my playback devices list, that doesn't work.  I will check out your suggestions.

Comment: Well, I I went through a bunch of trial and error removing the drivers and reinstalling them.  The only "compatibility mode" that it would work under was Windows Vista (not even the service packs).  The behavior remains the same.  When I connect, it immediately disconnects and it never shows up in the playback devices.  I guess I just need to hope that #9 happens someday.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue with a pair of Sony DR-BT50 headphones/headset. I followed [these instructions](http://windows7forums.com/windows-7-hardware/8235-how-add-a2dp-support-windows-7-a.html) and it has been working so far quite well.

> Windows 7 came with no A2DP support and MS asked bluetooth hardware manufacturer to add this feature in driver upgrade. All bluetooth hardware on laptop where most of the time we need A2DP are made by Broadcomm (widcomm software), Toshiba or CSR. The last 2 manufacturer seem to have A2DP in Vista which should work in W7 but for Broadcomm nothing around.
>
> I have a Motorola S9 that I wanted to connect to Dell d410 laptop with no success. This old dell laptop comes with a BT 355 internal blutooth adapter and refused to connect to my headset. After looking around for a few time a figured out how to enable A2DP in Windows 7.
>
> 1. Download this driver from Anycomm a German headset company:
>
>    http://www.oyla.de/cgi-bin/designs/rot/index.cgi?page=text&id=404641441255948643
> 2. Uninstall all your Bluetooth devices in device manger and ask to delete software also.
> 3. Install the downloaded software natively (no compatibiliy mode needed)
> 4. scan for hardware changes in device manager...it should install all devices including an audio handsfree driver.
> 5. Scan for your bluetooth audio and connect.
> 6. Go to you audio output devices and select the headset as an output.
>
> Enjoy stereo bluetooth music and movies!

Good luck. Windows and A2DP has not been friendly for me.

Answer (score 1):

Use [BlueSoleil](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BlueSoleil) software. I tried everything, like the Broadcom, but the only solution is BlueSoleil software. I have a Plantronix 210 Explorer and it's not working with Skype either.

Answer (score 0):

The file available for download at the site below is the answer to the question. The Broadcom file did not work for me though it updated the Bluetooth software. Even Windows Update doesn't give the working solution. Install it and restart the computer to start using the Bluetooth headset.

> http://support.gateway.com/support/drivers/getFile.asp?id=23452&dscr=Broadcom%20BRM2045%20and%20BRM2046%20Bluetoot%20h%20Driver%20Version%206.2.1.500&uid=24766478