# I want to use my mobile phone to play audio from my computer using Bluetooth

Tags: windows-7, audio, bluetooth

How can I connect my mobile phone to a computer over Bluetooth, so I can play sound using the phone's speaker?

I would like to do two things using Bluetooth:

1. Play computer audio over the mobile phone speaker.
2. Play computer audio using my headset.

Comment: I can rewrite the question if the mods will reopen. Essentially MUDIT wants to be able to play comptuer audio through his mobile phone's speaker, and the Bluetooth headset. The latter, at least, is actually possible.

Comment: @MUDIT, please post the exact model of telephone and headset you have. Also, do you already have Bluetooth set up on your computer, or will you need to install a Bluetooth adapter on the system?

Comment: What you're probably looking for is an A2DP client for your phone. Try searching for that.

Comment: Related: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/5796/can-an-android-phone-be-used-as-a-bluetooth-headset-speakers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10180895/how-to-enable-a2dp-sink-functionality-in-android https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-discuss/S1W4oSzG24M

Answer (score 1):

http://www.rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/

This software will work exactly as desired, except over wifi, rather than over bluetooth. This solution is for your phone. Hopefully using wifi is OK for your needs.

For the headset, you should just connect your headset to the computer (using bluetooth) and that's all. Choose the newly set up headset as your audio output and you're ready to go.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that most mobile phones can function as external speakers/headsets.

However, the answer to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/23774/how-to-play-audio-through-a-bluetooth-headset-in-windows-7) will let you play computer audio over your Bluetooth headset.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **free** Version of "Soundwire" to do so, except it works over your local (W)Lan. But that shouldn't be a problem, because most of the PCs don't have a bluetooth adapter anyways.