# My Bluetooth headset gives discontinuous audio while listening to music

Tags: windows-7, bluetooth, headset

While using my Bluetooth headset to listen to songs in my laptop(Win 7), the songs are discontinuous as if it were pausing and unpausing every second.

Comment: check out [this thread](http://superuser.com/questions/23774/how-do-i-play-audio-through-a-bluetooth-headset-in-windows-7)

Comment: @Raystafarian How are the issues related?

Comment: What bluetooth are you using? Windows doesn’t include bth headset support.

Comment: @DanielBeck to ensure it's installed properly, OP never mentioned what OP has tried so far or if he knows this or that is the specific problem, may as well start at the beginning. It's a poorly formed question, but can be improved by listing the steps already taken