# Trust Bluetooth 4.0 Dongle and Bluetooth Headset

Tags: bluetooth, headset, trust

Firstly, I'm writing this after 5 hours of nonstop struggle to make it work, so I searched into the deepest websites from Google, and tried many things.

**I have**

- Trust Bluetooth 4.0 USB adapter ([link](http://www.trust.com/products/product.aspx?artnr=18187))
- Samsung HM1500 Bluetooth Headset
- Windows 7 64-bit Desktop PC

**Facts**

- Nothing wrong with the headset. (*it works, tested on a phone and a
  laptop. Problem is all about bluetooth dongle and its driver.*)
- Trust BT adapter can send and receive files even without any
  driver.
- I can pair successfully without any driver too.
- In Headset's Properties, Services tab, Handsfree and Headset services are checked.

**Problem**

When I pair with my BT headset, I cannot see it as a sound playback device.
Also when I double-click the headset device icon in Bluetooth Devices, 
**in laptop:** it opens a connection window where I can connect and disconnect to that device - perfect! 
**in desktop:** it opens the properties window, even though Handsfree and Headset services are checked *(I check them explicitly, in laptop they came as already checked)* - Problem!

**Unsuccessful driver installations**

- The driver on the Trust's website says "**Error 1606** Could not access Network Location" on start, so it doesn't get installed.
- The driver on Broadcom ([link](http://www.broadcom.com/support/bluetooth/update.php)) is being closed with Windows's that classic "**has stopped working**" error on validation step, so it doesn't get installed too.
  *(Those tests made more than once)*

**Successful installation**

In the Win64 folder of Trust's driver from their website, if I install through "BTW.msi", it doesn't give me *Error 1606* and it gets installed.

**Then the problem:** When I try to start bluetooth from start menu (or it gets started at Windows startup), an error popup says: "*BtBalloon.dll is missing...*" so it doesn't start.
I found *BBalloon.dll* in the driver folder, I renamed it to *BtBalloon.dll*, moved into *Windows/system32* and *Windows/SysWOW64* folders, and it seems working. Or maybe it gets closed behind the scenes. The bluetooth icon is there with or without this driver since Windows has it.

**Bluetooth Peripheral Device**

First it didn't get installed from Windows Update. After, I showed the driver folder path in Device Manager and pressed "Explore in this location". Surprisingly, it's being found as "Handsfree" driver. Now even I uninstall the drivers, it still can see the Handsfree.

But still, no playback device.

**Test on XP**:
driver gets installed successfully, but weird I cannot connect to device. I see the handset connection window at least, it says disconnected, but there's no "connect" button.
**Test on another Windows 7 64-Bit Computer**:
Error 1606
**Test on Windows 7 32-Bit** (Virtual Machine):
Error 1606
**Error 1606 screenshot**: http://i47.tinypic.com/21mgq2r.png

Any ideas to guide me? I'm out of them.

Comment: See this: http://superuser.com/q/23774/160458

Comment: Already checked that, doesn't work. That driver is for Dell BH200, not installing for me. Broadcom driver is not installing, I already mentioned that too.

Comment: Did you specifically try the 64-bit driver here? http://www.trust.com/products/productdrivers.aspx?artnr=18187

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: Great question! Well-researched. I've +1ed and linked to the question in the [Root Access](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/root-access) StackExchange chatroom (SuperUser is part of the StackExchange network, so it's "within" the site). I don't have specific experience with this headset, but maybe some of us can help you walk through some trial and error steps if you join the chat?

Comment: Thanks @allquixotic also I want to point out that there's nothing wrong with the headset. Everything is about the driver of Trust Bluetooth 4.0

Comment: I've updated the post and put more tests, still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Driver from [Bluetooth 3.0 USB Adapter](http://www.trust.com/products/product.aspx?artnr=17772) worked with Bluetooth 4.0 dongle.

What a company, cannot even make a driver to their products.

Answer (score 1):

I confirm this. I can't see any services available under "Properties, Services" tab either. If either my Sandstrom bluetooth headphones or my Sony audio dock are freshly paired and the services tab is open for a few seconds there is a flash  of "Paired, Connected" under the audio device icon in the device control panel - but it disappears within a second and reverts to "Paired". I've tried the supplied v2 software/drivers for XP and the downloaded v4 with no different result.

I have the Trust Bluetooth 3.0 adapter and its Bluetooth Suite software and with a fresh install the adapter works as expected with both my Bluetooth audio devices. I replicated all this on a second Win XP SP3 PC too.

I have sent details to Trust Support but given other people's problems am not expecting much. I'm pretty sure that it is not your heaphones at fault, and it is probably the Trust adapter. Unfortunately I bought two!

If I don't get joy from Trust soon I may try running the 4.0 adapter with the 3.0 Bluetooth software suite under XP.

I bought the additional Bluetooth 4.0 adapters because Trust claims they are windows 8 compatible but they don't make such a claim for the 3.0 adapter!

It may help others to know that I was previously able to install the v3 software/drivers into Windows 8 Pro on my laptop and to use the Bluetooth 3.0 adapter successfully with my Sony audio dock, but I had to unpack the driver package in Windows 7 compatability mode before I could install it. The troubleshooter's suggested Windows XP compatability mode unpack doesn't work.