# "A remote device needs a Bluetooth Passkey" when trying to pair with a mouse

Tags: windows-7, mouse, bluetooth

I have two Windows 7 PC's at my desk.  I installed a Class 1 Bluetooth adapter on the first system, and was able to connect to a mouse using the Add Device option in Devices.  It worked pretty smoothly.

The second PC (Windows 7 just like the first) is not playing nicely.  The adapter is installed with no errors in device manager.   When I go to Add Device, the mouse is not shown/detected.

If I click the Bluetooth icon in the taskbar, I see the bluetooth mouse (which is turned on with fresh batteries).   This is what appears when I attempt to pair:

[image]

Why is this happening on my second Windows 7 machine?   Where do I find the Bluetooth Passkey?

Comment: Similar/Related: [Windows asks me for a bluetooth pairing code for my headset](http://superuser.com/questions/694540/windows-asks-me-for-a-bluetooth-pairing-code-for-my-headset)

Answer (score 2):

Easy fix, if not very obvious.  Most mice apparently use "0000" or "1234" as passkey.  I entered 0000 and am now paired.

Comment: Many/Most BT devices (not just mice) use one of those two (by default), sometimes 1111.